# Mathematically manipulating error resources

Tags: error

Hate asking such a general question, but I'm so unfamiliar with statistics in general that I don't know what to search or where to find the answer.

I'd like to learn how to manipulate errors. Like, if I had a function $f\left(x,y,z\right)$, and I knew $\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z$, what the error of $\sigma_{f}$ is.

Comment: Search for [delta method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Non-linear_combinations)

Comment: Search for [transforming random variables](https://www.google.com/search?q=transforming+random+variables)